# Enable remote access to Postgres Server 9.3

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, remote-server

Could anyone please tell me how to enable remote access to the PostgreSQL server 9.3? 
I tried the steps given in the following guide
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

I was hoping that the steps would be similar but when try to restart the server I get the following error: 
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data is missing. Use "service postgresql-9.3 initdb" to initialize the cluster first.
Since I am trying this for the first time I might be missing a basic step. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you followed the advice in the error message? ("*Use 'service postgresql-9.3 initdb'*")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not enabling remote access, but that your install is dying. Maybe you blindly copypasted some config.

Step back to your original configuration, edit pg_hba.conf (it is self-explanatory), and everything will be okay.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't pointing to the right directory and this was causing the problem. Thanks!